# How can I implement a 'main' method in a class in C++?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
static class EntranceClass {
public:
    static void RegisterSomething()
    {
    }

    static int main()
    {
        RegisterSomething();
        return 0;
    }
} // <-- Expected unqualified-id at the end
```

I'm getting the following error:

> expected unqualified-id at end of input main.cpp Problem

Is there a solution?

Comment: C++ differs from Java here.  You don't have a "public static void main()" here, just an "int main()" that you place at file level.

Comment: You are also missing a semicolon after that last closing brace.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was well received in the first place. What OP was trying to do a) makes little sense and b) *has nothing to do with the cause of the reported error*.

Comment: What was the intent? Having the main entry point to the program being the (static) member function? Something related to (automatic) initialisation at program startup? Order of initialisation at program startup?

Comment: The intent is important. Some of the answers are good guesses and good interpretations, but without the actual intent it is impossible to know what the real answer should be. Perhaps the OP should provide some input? He or she is still active (*"Last seen this week"*).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is referring to the use of the `static` keyword before the class definition - the compiler expects a variable name after that (as in C++ there is no such thing as a `static class`).

And if you want to use `static int EntranceMain::main(void)` as your program's entry point, then one way to do it is to tell that to your linker, i.e., give it a full, decorated name of that function. This is highly dependent on which compiler and linker you use, so you need to refer to their documentation. But using that will probably mean you need to include the startup code (e.g., [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) initialisation).

Note that this is not so standard-compliant, though.

Comment: You don't tell it to the linker.  What you do is something like "int main() { return EntranceMain::main(); }" at global level.  Otherwise, you're writing an unportable hack (which may go away with any change to the implementation) instead of C++.

Comment: main, is a bit generic for a method name.

Comment: `main` was already mentioned by others, this is just another way. I didn't say it's the best; and if you think the wording is bad, feel free to edit.

Comment: Its not true, that there are no static methods in C++. A classmember as i.e. static int myFunction() is perfectly legal.

Comment: I know. I said "static class".

Answer (score 30):

`main` is just `main`. It is simply a function:

```
class EntranceClass
{
    ...
}; // <-- Note the semicolon

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: It's worth emphasizing the need for the semicolon at the end of the class declaration.

Answer (score 10):

According to the standard, you're not writing a true `main` function.

Section 3.6.1, paragraph 3:  "The function `main` shall not be used (3.2) within a program.  The linkage (3.5) of `main` is implementation-defined.  A program that declares `main` to be `inline` or `static` is ill-formed.  The name `main` is not otherwise reserved.  [*Example:*  member function, classes, and enumerations can be called `main`, as can entities in other namespaces.]"

This means that, by declaring a member function `main`, you're just declaring a member function.  It has no special significance, and doesn't mean anything in the class can be called independently.  The program would mean entirely the same thing if you substituted `snicklefrazz` for that function name and all references.

Stylistically, `snicklefrazz` would be better, since it wouldn't lead to any possible conclusion with the standard `main` function.

Section 3.6.1, paragraph 1:  "A program shall contain a global function called `main`, which is the designated start of the program.  It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a `main` function."

This means that, unless you're writing in what the standard calls a freestanding environment (typically used in writing embedded systems), you need to define a `main` global function, and this is where the program starts.

In Java, a class can have a `main` method, which is where the program begins when the class is invoked.  This is not the case in C++, and there is no way to accomplish this directly.

(And, as others have mentioned, a `class` cannot be `static`, and a class definition ends with a semicolon.)

Comment: i want to add that the first function in a program would be start, ofc only when the process is loaded by the loader, so you could basicly declare any function as entry point, but you would need to modify the program sections

Answer (score 7):

You may have forgotten the semicolon after the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the [constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) of the object.

Anyway, try to remove `static`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like horrible coding style to me to be putting your main into a class, but if you really wanted to do it I think the implementation would be more like so:

```
class Foo{
public:
    int main(){ return 0; };
};

Foo bar;

int Foo::main(){
    bar.main();
}
```

As I said though, this seems to be very bad coding style. You're better off building your class in a .hpp file and then linking it into your *program_main.cpp* (via #include "foo.hpp") which has the *int main(){ return 0; }* function for you to call the class.

Comment: Agreed - woe to the person who has to then maintain that program after this programmer has left the effort.

Answer (score 1):

- In C++ you can have "global" functions, i. e. functions that are not members ("methods" in Java lingo) of any class.
- By default the entry point to a C++ program is a "global" `main()` function that in general looks like this:

  ```cpp
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    // Do stuff
  }
  ```

  The arguments to `main()` allow your program to take command line arguments.  They can be omitted like so

  ```cpp
  int main()
  {
    // Do stuff
  }
  ```

  in which case your program does not take any arguments.  When a program exits normally, the convention is for `main()` to return 0.  A return value other than 0 is typically used to indicate an error.
- There is no notion of a static class in C++.  You can have static member functions and data members, or static global variables (different meaning of static inherited from C).
- You need a semicolon after the class definition.

Comment: You may want to add a note about the alternate main prototype: "int main()".

Answer (score -1):

One trick you can do is to create a class that is called something like "BaseApp" that is derived from, and then implement a virtual function that calls through to the real version.

```
class BaseApp
{
public:
   virtual void   EntryPoint() = 0;
   static  BaseApp* GetApp() { return this; }
};
```

Then just derive a class from it, implement an EntryPoint(), and define your object.

```
class SpecializedApp: public BaseApp
{
public:
   void EntryPoint() { ... }
};

SpecializedApp g_App;
```

Then, you have main() that calls through to it:

```
void main()
{
   BaseApp::GetApp()->EntryPoint();
}
```

This is a way that you can have main be a type of generic startup routine that can call into different entry points depending on how things are linked in.  You could have a Win32 class or a standard C class on top of BaseApp.

Comment: A static member function cannot use 'this' since it operates on no instance at all.